# Comparing pandas column with values in list and returning higher lower bound values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list, which is unsorted but contains uniques values. Below one is just for example.

```
lst = [1,3,4,6]
```

and a pandas column, which looks something like below:

```
A
3
4
```

I want two more columns with upper and lower bound values and want to create two pandas column as below

```
 A UpperA LowerA
 3   4      1
 4   6      3
```

logic for UpperA should be like this
`UpperA= min(i for i in lst if i>k)`

logic for LowerA should be like this
`LowerA = max(i for i in lst if i<k)`

Here `k` is the value from column A.

Comment: Have you tried anything? I don't see a question here and there is a lot of gaps in the spec. What happens if the element isn't in the list? Is the list guaranteed to be sorted ascending? What about duplicates in `lst`?

Comment: Is the question clear now?

Comment: the elements both in the list and in the pandas columns are integer. There is no need for the list to be sorted, this is just for example. we are subsetting the list based on column values and then taking max or min out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge_asof` to get values above or below A:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [3, 4]})
lst = [1,3,4,6]
lst_df = pd.DataFrame({"bounderies": lst})

res = pd.merge_asof(df, lst_df, left_on="A", 
                               right_on="bounderies", 
                               direction = "backward", 
                               allow_exact_matches=False)
res.rename(columns = {"bounderies": "lowerA"}, inplace=True)

res = pd.merge_asof(res, lst_df, left_on="A", 
                               right_on="bounderies", 
                               direction = "forward", 
                               allow_exact_matches=False)

res.rename(columns = {"bounderies": "upperA"}, inplace=True)
```

The result is:

```
   A  lowerA  upperA
0  3       1       4
1  4       3       6
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes...thanks for the code :)

Comment: Do you mind accepting it as an answer for future generations?

Comment: sure i think so